# Reading data from a file and save in list in C

Tags: c, file, arraylist

I've just started a little Project to learn C and got a couple of problems.
Trying to read a file from stdin and and save strings to list with a specified key.

The structure of the files looks like this:

```
1sfa23sab:1najsf9,aksfafio2413,asfjla2345,asjfiao242
25kldg:asfkn36,akal,l,slgjii90345-234
```

I've already managed to read the file char by char like this:

```
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF )
    {
        create_list(c);
    }
```

and defined a special data type for my list:

```
typedef struct data_id
{
    char id;
    int marker;
    int key;
    void* ptr;
} data_id;
data_id *nodeList;
```

I want to save the characters until ":", "-", "," or "LF/CR" appears as one id entry in my list with a specific key. So every ID should also have a key. The part after a "-" is a marker which should also be saved in the list.
e.g. am entry should be like id=slgjii90345, key=10 and marker=234 ...

The create_list function I've written so far is:

```
void create_list(input){
    nodeList = malloc(sizeof *nodeList * 10);
    if (islower(input) || isdigit(input)){
        if (m_flag == true && isdigit(input)){
            nodeList[num_id].marker += (char)input;
            printf("%d", nodeList[num_id].marker);
        }
        else{
            nodeList[num_id].id += (char)input;
            m_flag = false;
        }
    }
    else if (input == '-')
    {
        m_flag = true;
        printf("\ndash detected, marker follows: ");
    }
    else if (input == '\n' || input == ',' || input == ':')
    {
        // printf("\nnext entry follows:\n");
        nodeList[num_id].marker = 0;
        nodeList[num_id].key = num_id;
        num_id++;
        m_flag = false;
    }
    // printf("%d", nodeList[num_id].marker);
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: Also, `data_id *nodeList = (data_id*) malloc(sizeof(void *) * 10);` should really be `data_id *nodeList = malloc(sizeof *nodeList * 10);`. And about `nodeList`, why do you allocate dynamically? And why `10` of the structures? Where does `num_id` come from?

Comment: Oh and `strcat(nodeList[num_id].id, (char)c)` will most likely give you a crash. The `str` prefix in `strcat` means *string*, as in concatenating one string to another string. `c` or even `(char) c` isn't a string.

Comment: So num_id is just my counter which I declared to be able to store and ID to the list and I'm trying to allocate dynamically because I don't really know how big the entries are gonna be. Just tried out the 10, because I thought the space I've allocated was to small

Comment: Both the `id` member as well as `c` are single characters. Neither can be strings. You probably need to take a few steps back, go find a beginners book and start reading from the beginning to freshen up the very basics of C.

Comment: I've managed to save the 'IDs', 'Keys' and the 'marker' in the array, but somehow they aren't available outside of the function even though 'nodeList' is declared globally.

Comment: With `nodeList = malloc(…)`, you are forgetting the previous list each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the original question post; several mistakes were pointed out in comments. Here's a usable variant of your code:

```
typedef struct data_id
{
    char id[13];            // allow strings up to length 12
    int key;
} data_id;

data_id *nodeList;          // accessible and persistent outside create_list
int num_id;

void create_list(char input[])
{
    int c = num_id++;       // index of created node
    nodeList = realloc(nodeList, sizeof *nodeList * num_id);
    if (!nodeList) exit(1);
    strcpy(nodeList[c].id, input);
    nodeList[c].key = num_id;
    printf("node_id: %s\n", input);
    printf("key: %d\n", num_id);
}
```

To read the file with the given separators and call `create_list` for each *id*, you can use this:

```
    for (char c[13]; scanf("%12[^-:,\n]%*c", c) != EOF; ) create_list(c);
```

> Is there a way to to have a `char id[]` variable with dynamically growing length?

Of course there are many ways. The easiest is if you have a POSIX.1-2008 conforming `scanf` - then you can use the `m` modifier to let it allocate a buffer of sufficient size:

```
typedef struct data_id
{
    char *id;               // allows strings of any length
    int key;
} data_id;
…
    nodeList[c].id = input; // instead of strcpy(nodeList[c].id, input);
…
    for (char *c; scanf("%m[^-:,\n]%*c", &c) != EOF; ) create_list(c);
```

Comment: Is there a way to to have a `char id[]` variable with dynamically growing length?

Comment: I added one way to the answer.